# How do you delay rendering a table

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a table with too many rows. It's really slow to render them all at once. I wonder how do you implement this feature? Is there already a library to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It`s called infinitescroll. I use this [library](https://binarymuse.github.io/ngInfiniteScroll/) which provides an directives to do this. The idea is simple, when you reach the end of page, this plugin calls your method that append more rows in your table. There are some examples that can help you. Hope it helps.